# Grading unsuccessful team work in a seminar

Tags: teaching, seminars

I'm the supervisor of a seminar.

A team of two students is preparing a common presentation for the seminar. The team has to write a report (a preliminary version for double-blind reviewing by other teams and a final version read by me) and give two talks; the team has a lot of freedom on how and what they do. The topic, the seminar dates, the duration, and the deadlines for handing in the reports and the slides are fixed.

I put the two together a few months ago (they had not known each other before, so I had to do all the organization via e-mail). They already submitted the preliminary version of the report more-or-less in time. However, 5 days before handling in the final report and 12 days before the presentation, one of them complained about the poor performance of another one. I asked them to clearly state their contributions by a particular deadline; one did so, while the other did not answer by the deadline. I offered them to split and am waiting for the answer.

I do care that all the participants of the seminar and me learn something new from the students' presentations.
Moreover, I get evaluated by the seminar participants anonymously; the evaluation goes to the department. I do care about good evaluation results, too.

How should I deal with such an unpleasant situation?

Answer (score 1):

This post might be relevant to you: [Should I hide the fact that I did a group assignment completely by myself?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91526/should-i-hide-the-fact-that-i-did-a-group-assignment-completely-by-myself)

Regarding your question:

You put them together a few months ago, and still you only get a complaint a few days before the deadline. Now, there are two possible cases:

1. They don't have a finished report by the deadline. In this case, I would take the appropriate steps. They had months to discuss the topic with you, to get into another team, etc., if they only come to you five days before the end, they have to take the consequences.
2. They have a finished report, but one of them claims to have done most of the work. In this case, you already took good steps, I would continue along this path. If the student doesn't answer, assume he dropped the course and act accordingly.

Regarding your evaluation, you should know that it is common for students who get a bad grade (like it might be the case for the lazy student here) to give a bad evaluation. The people reading these evaluations should also be aware about this and as long as it is only a single one that stands out negatively, it shouldn't affect you too much. Be prepared to explain and justify the steps you have taken, e.g. offering the students to split.

Comment: Thank you! It is between cases 1 and 2 as of now. I adapted the question accordingly.

Comment: There already has been one early dropout from another team. So, if the second student drops out, I'm likely to get two negative gradings, in your opinion, right?

Comment: @LeonMeier It'll depend on why the other student dropped out. If he or she just had too much to do, dropping your seminar may have had the least impact on graduating. Or it might have been the hardest and taking the most amount of time. If a student feels that the workload is too much for the amount of credits--bad review.

Comment: @mkennedy unclear. There was insufficient feedback from the side of the student to me.

Comment: @LeonMeier There's no way you can predict what kind of feedback/review a student's going to give. Someone may do fine in class but hate your clothes to the point that they'll write a bad review or think the class was too easy or too hard or whatever.

Comment: @LeonMeier You should drive your actions by what seems fair, not by what looks good on your evaluation.

Comment: @ShakeBaby why? If Leon is judged on the evaluation he receives and he cares about his future, then he should care about the evaluation. To the extent that he is not, to that extent he shouldn't. You're confusing how the world should be with how the world is. Ideally, teachers don't care about evaluations and only do what's best for transferring knowledge. But that's not what they're evaluated on. It would be poor to advise someone to do something based on a wrong model of how the world works. That's akin to telling someone to jump off a building because they should be able to fly.